# Asymptotics of second kind Bessel function

Tags: asymptotics, bessel-functions

I would like to obtain asymptotic of $K_{i\nu}(\nu z)$, which the modified Bessel function of the second kind of order $i\nu$ for large $\nu$. The parameter $\nu$ is positive, $\nu>0$ and $z >0$, too.

I have read the corresponding chapter from the book by Olver ("Asymptotics and special functions") (according to DLMF, pages 378-382 from Chapter 8 are relevant). However, my understanding is still poor. Olver suggests as an exercise to derive this asymptotics and states the final answer,
$$K_{i\nu}(\nu z)\approx\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2\nu}}\frac{\exp(-\pi\nu/2-\nu\zeta)}{(z^2-1)^{1/4}}\left(\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^s\hat{U}_s(\hat{p})}{\nu^s}+\phi_n(\nu,z)\right), \tag{*}$$
where $\zeta=\sqrt{z^2-1}-\text{Arcsec}(z)$. I have tried to rederive this expression and in general I understand how it appears.

However Olver refers to original work by Balogh ([link](https://doi.org/10.1137/0115114)). I have read this paper and my understanding disappeared. One of the final results in this paper is the following expression,
$$K_{i\nu}(\nu z) = \frac{\pi\sqrt{2}e^{-\pi\nu/2}}{\nu^{1/3}}\left(\frac{\eta}{z^2-1}\right)^{1/4}\left(\text{Ai}(\beta)+\frac{\text{Ai}'(\beta)}{\nu^{4/3}}+...\right),(**)$$
where quantities $\eta$ and $\beta$ are given by
$$\frac{2}{3}\eta^{3/2}=\sqrt{z^2-1}-\text{Arcsec}(z),\quad \beta=-\nu^{2/3}\eta.$$

Finally, there is one more paper by Dunster (which is the most of interest for me, [link](https://doi.org/10.1137/0521055)), where the quite similar (up to some redefinitions) expression appears.

In addition, Dunster states that $(**)$ and $(*)$ coincides (cf. (4.8) with (4.25)). I tried my best but still cannot connect $(*)$ and $(**)$ to each other. I do not understand what should I do (I tried to perform large-$\nu$ expansion in Airy functions).

**My final goal is to find large $\nu$ asymptotics for $I_{i\nu}(\nu z)$ and $K_{i\nu}(\nu z)$. Can anyone clarify how $(**)$ becomes $(*)$ or simply give more refences with more details?**

Further investigation is performed around well-known uniform expansion,
$$K_{\nu}(\nu z)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2\nu}}\frac{e^{-\nu\gamma}}{(1+z^2)^{1/4}}\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}(-1)^s\frac{U_s(p)}{\nu^s}, \tag{***}$$
where $U_s(p)$ is some function and $p=(1+z^2)^{-1/2}$. I am not interested in this term). Naively, I can just replace $\nu\rightarrow i\nu$ and $z\rightarrow -iz$ in order to deal with $K_{i\nu}(\nu z)$. Surprisingly for me, it works: I reproduce the result in Olver book (the very first formula). The most tricky moment is to remind that
$$\text{Arcsec}(z)=i\ln\frac{z}{1+\sqrt{1-z^2}},$$
which seems correct. Finally, there is the following mapping (based on Olver book, Ch. 8),
$$\hat{U}_s(x)=i^sU_s(-ix),\quad \hat{p}=(z^2-1)^{-1/2}.$$

Comment: I plotted the starred formulas for $\nu$=20 and $10<z<30$ and it is apparent that two-stars is much better.  The options are (1)  that one-star has a mistake in the formula, either of that of the original author or as transcribed by you or (2) the formula one-star is meant to be on a much more circumscribed range.  I'm betting on (1).  I wouldn't try to reduce a formula to another (though your instinct about using asymptotics for the Airy function is correct), until I'm 95+% sure they are equivalent, at least over a certain range, and plots can do that for you.

Comment: @skbmoore in the very first expression ( * expr) I have omitted the "rest". So, the ** contains such "rest" (for me it seems that is Airy functions)

Comment: @skbmoore I have added some info but I still do not take into account the function $U_s(p)$. From my point of view, it means that in (**) I should expand Airy functions for large argument

Comment: From the formula given, it appears that you must take into account $U_0.$ (Of course, it may be identically 1.)

Comment: The factor $\sum_s + \phi_n$ can be ignored if we only want to show asymptotic equivalence. In terms of $\beta$, the limit of $(**)/(*)$ is equal to
$$2 \sqrt \pi \lim_{\beta \to \infty}
 \beta^{1/4} e^{2 \beta^{3/2}/3} \operatorname {Ai}(\beta).$$
Note that we need $z > 1$ if we want $(*)$ and $(**)$ to be asymptotically equivalent to $K_{i \nu}(z \nu)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I begin with a discussion of the [uniform asymptotic expansion](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.41.ii) of $K_\nu(\nu z)$. We start with the [integral representation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E9)
$$\tag{1}
K_\nu  (z) = \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - z\cosh t} \cosh (\nu t){\rm d}t}  = \frac{1}{2}\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - z\cosh t} {\rm e}^{ - \nu t} {\rm d}t} ,$$
which is valid when $\nu>0$ and $|\arg z|\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. It is convenient to work with the variable
$\zeta  \in \mathcal{D}: = \left\{ {w:\Re w \geq 0,\; \left| \Im w \right| \leq \frac{\pi }{2}},\; w\neq 0 \right\}$. Note that the function $\operatorname{csch}$ is a bijection between $\mathcal{D}$ and the sector $|\arg z|\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. Thus, by $(1)$,
$$
K_\nu  (\nu \operatorname{csch} \zeta ) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\exp ( - \nu f(t,\zeta )){\rm d}t} ,
$$
where
$$
f(t,\zeta ) = \operatorname{csch} \zeta \cosh t + t,
$$
provided $\nu>0$. The saddle points of $f(t,\zeta )$ are
$$
t_e^{(n)}  :=  - \zeta  + 2n\pi {\rm i}, \quad t_o^{(n)}  := \zeta  + (2n + 1)\pi {\rm i},
$$
for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence, by deforming the path of integration,
$$\tag{2}
K_\nu  (\nu \operatorname{csch} \zeta ) = \frac{{{\rm e}^{ - \nu (\coth \zeta  - \zeta )} }}{2}\int_{\mathscr{C}_e^{(0)} } {\exp ( - \nu (f(t,\zeta ) - f(t_e^{(0)} ,\zeta ))){\rm d}t} ,
$$
where $\mathscr{C}_e^{(0)}$ is the doubly infinite steepest descent path through the saddle $t_e^{(0)}$. We now parametrise the path of steepest descent $\mathscr{C}_e^{(0)}$ by introducing the new variable $s$:
$$\tag{3}
s := s(t,\zeta ) := f(t,\zeta ) - f(t_e^{(0)} ,\zeta ).
$$
Note that, since $\nu>0$ and the definiton of $\mathscr{C}_e^{(0)}$, $s$ is real and positive on each half of the contour $\mathscr{C}_e^{(0)}$ divided by $t_e^{(0)}$. Thus, corresponding to each $s>0$, there are two values of $t$, which we denote by $t^+$ and $t^-$ that satisfy $(3)$. With this parametrisation, $(2)$ becomes
$$\tag{4}
K_\nu  (\nu \operatorname{csch} \zeta ) = \frac{{{\rm e}^{ - \nu (\coth \zeta  - \zeta )} }}{2}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\rm e}^{-\nu s}F(s,\zeta ){\rm d}s ,
$$
where
$$
F(s,\zeta ) := \frac{{{\rm d}t^+(s,\zeta )}}{{{\rm d}s}}-\frac{{{\rm d}t^-(s,\zeta )}}{{{\rm d}s}}.
$$
Since $s(t,\zeta)$ is entire and has no finite asymptotic values, the only singularities of $t(s,\zeta)$ (and hence $F(s,\zeta )$) are branch points located at
$$
s_e^{(n)} := f(t_e^{(n)} ,\zeta ) - f(t_e^{(0)} ,\zeta ) = 2\pi {\rm i}n,
$$
$$
s_o^{(n)} := f(t_o^{(n)} ,\zeta ) - f(t_e^{(n)} ,\zeta ) =  - 2(\coth \zeta  - \zeta ) + (2n + 1)\pi {\rm i},
$$
for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Note that $F(s,\zeta )$ is the difference of the values of $t(s,\zeta)$ on the two sides of the branch cut running from $s_e^{(0)}=0$. Now we can complexify $\nu$ in $(4)$ by rotating the path of integration so that $\nu s$ remains real and positive. This process works until the path runs into one of the singularities of $F(s,\zeta)$. There are two cases that have to be considered.

$(i)$ If $\Re (\coth \zeta  - \zeta ) \geq 0$, $\zeta \in \mathcal{D}$, then all the singularities lie in the closed left half-plane $\Re s \leq 0$. This region corresponds to the grey region in the closed right half-plane in the variable $z=\operatorname{csch} \zeta$ depicted on Figure 8.3 on page 380 of Olver's book *Asymptotics and Special Functions*. Since $F(s,\zeta)$ remains bounded for $\Re s>0$, an application of the extended Watson lemma (Theorem 3.3 on page 114 of Olver's book) yields
$$\tag{5}
K_\nu  (\nu \operatorname{csch} \zeta ) \sim \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{2\nu \coth \zeta }}} {\rm e}^{ - \nu (\coth \zeta  - \zeta )} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty ( - 1)^n \frac{U_n (\tanh \zeta )}{\nu ^n} 
$$ as $\nu \to \infty$ in the sector $|\arg \nu|\leq\pi-\delta\,(<\pi)$ provided that $\Re (\coth \zeta  - \zeta ) \geq 0$, $\zeta \in \mathcal{D}$. Here, we follow the [standard notation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.41.ii).

$(ii)$ If $\Re (\coth \zeta  - \zeta )< 0$, $\zeta \in \mathcal{D}$, then the singularities $s_o^{(n)}$ move into the right half-plane. This region corresponds to the white region in the closed right half-plane in the variable $z=\operatorname{csch} \zeta$ depicted on Figure 8.3 on page 380 of Olver's book. It is not hard to show that in this case $2n\pi \leq \Im s_o^{(n)} \leq (2n + 2)\pi$. In particular $0 \leq \Im s_o^{(0)} \leq 2\pi$ and $- 2\pi  \leq \Im s_o^{( - 1)} \leq 0$. Since $\Re s_o^{(n)}$ is the same for all $n$, the path rotation argument works until we hit one of the two singularities $s_o^{(0)}$ or $s_o^{(-1)}$. Thus, the $\nu$-sector of validity of $(5)$ will depend on the phases of these singularities in this case. Nevertheless, we can say that $(5)$ will definitely be valid as long as $|\arg \nu|\leq\frac{\pi}{2}-\delta\,(<\frac{\pi}{2})$. Furthermore, if $z=\operatorname{csch} \zeta$ is bounded away from the imaginary axis inside the white domain, $(5)$ remains valid for $|\arg \nu|\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Now, let me turn to your problem. We see from the above analysis that in order to derive the asymptotics of $K_{\mathrm{i}\nu}(\nu z)$ from that of $K_{\nu}(\nu z)$ via the substitutions $\nu \to \mathrm{i}\nu$ and $z \to \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{i}}z$ ($\nu$ and $z$ are real and positive), we have to assume $z>1$ (a special case of case $(i)$ above). This is because if $0<z\leq 1$, we are on the imaginary axis inside the white region and the asymptotic expansion of $K_{\nu}(\nu z)$ is not valid for $|\arg \nu| =\frac{\pi}{2}$. Indeed, Olver says in Exercise 8.3 on page 382 that, in particular, $0< z\leq 1$ has to be excluded. The expansion for the case $0<z<1$ is \begin{align*}\tag{6}
K_{\mathrm{i}\nu } (\nu \operatorname{sech}\alpha ) \sim \sqrt {\frac{{2\pi}}{\nu\tanh \alpha}} {\mathrm e}^{ - \pi \nu /2} & \left( \cos \omega \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{U_{2n} (\coth \alpha )}}{{\nu ^{2n} }}} \right. \\ & \left. \qquad - \sin \omega \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{U_{2n + 1} (\coth \alpha )}}{{\nu ^{2n} }}}  \right)
\end{align*}
as $\nu \to +\infty$ with $\alpha>0$ and $\omega  = \nu (\alpha  - \tanh \alpha ) - \frac{\pi }{4}$. Note that Balogh mistakenly writes $\sec \alpha$ in place of $\operatorname{sech}\alpha$. For the case $z>1$, the substitutions $\nu \to \mathrm{i}\nu$ and $\zeta \to \mathrm{i}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta\right)$, $0 < \beta  < \frac{\pi}{2}$, in $(5)$ give
$$\tag{7}
K_{\mathrm{i}\nu } (\nu \sec \beta ) \sim \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{2\nu \tan \beta }}} {\mathrm e}^{ - \pi \nu /2}\mathrm{e}^{ - \nu (\tan \beta  - \beta )} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\mathrm{i}^n \frac{{U_n (\mathrm{i}\cot \beta )}}{{\nu ^n }}} 
$$
as $\nu \to +\infty$. Note that due to the properties of $U_n$, the coefficients of this expansion are real. Both of these expansions break down near the turning point $z=1$ (i.e., when $\alpha=0$ or $\beta=0$). In fact, both of these expansions are useful only if $|\nu-z| \gg \nu^{1/3}$.

Now, there are two ways to overcome the above problem.

$(i)$ For fixed (complex) $\tau$, the following transitional expansion holds:
$$
\frac{2}{\pi }{\rm e}^{\pi \nu /2} K_{\mathrm{i}\nu } (\nu  + \tau \nu ^{1/3} ) \sim \frac{{2^{4/3} }}{{\nu ^{1/3} }}\operatorname{Ai}(2^{1/3} \tau )\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{P_n (\tau )}}{{\nu ^{2n/3} }}}  + \frac{{2^{5/3} }}{\nu }\operatorname{Ai}'(2^{1/3} \tau )\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{Q_n (\tau )}}{{\nu ^{2n/3} }}} 
$$
as $\nu \to +\infty$, where $P_n$ and $Q_n$ are polynomials in $\tau$. In particular,
$$
P_0 (\tau ) = 1,\quad Q_0 (\tau ) =  - \frac{3}{{10}}\tau ^2 .
$$
In fact, the above expansion remains valid as long as $|\tau| =o(\nu^{4/15})$. Note that the large parameter $\nu$ is not present in the argument of the Airy function and its derivative.

$(ii)$ The second option is to use the expansion in terms of the Airy function and its derivative obtained by Balogh. This expansion is uniformly valid for $z>0$ as $\nu \to +\infty$. One may separate Balogh's result into two cases:
\begin{align*}
\frac{{{\rm e}^{\pi \nu /2} }}{\pi }K_{\mathrm{i}\nu } (\nu \operatorname{sech}\alpha ) \sim & \; \sqrt {\frac{{12^{1/3} (\alpha  - \tanh \alpha )^{1/3} }}{{\tanh \alpha }}} \\ & \times \left( {\frac{{\operatorname{Ai}(\nu ^{2/3} \zeta )}}{{\nu ^{1/3} }}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{A_n (\zeta )}}{{\nu ^{2n} }}}  + \frac{{\operatorname{Ai}'(\nu ^{2/3} \zeta )}}{{\nu ^{5/3} }}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{B_n (\zeta )}}{{\nu ^{2n} }}} } \right)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\frac{{{\rm e}^{\pi \nu /2} }}{\pi }K_{\mathrm{i}\nu } (\nu \sec \beta ) \sim & \;\sqrt {\frac{{12^{1/3} (\tan \beta  - \beta )^{1/3} }}{{\tan \beta }}} \\ & \times \left( \frac{{\operatorname{Ai}(\nu ^{2/3} \zeta )}}{{\nu ^{1/3} }}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{A_n (\zeta )}}{{\nu ^{2n} }}}  + \frac{{\operatorname{Ai}'(\nu ^{2/3} \zeta )}}{{\nu ^{5/3} }}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{B_n (\zeta )}}{{\nu ^{2n} }}} \right)
\end{align*}
as $\nu \to +\infty$, with $\zeta  =  - (3/2)^{2/3} (\alpha  - \tanh \alpha )^{2/3}$ in the first- and $\zeta  = (3/2)^{2/3} (\tan \beta  - \beta )^{2/3}$ in the second expansion, respectively. These expansions have no issue at $\alpha=\beta=0$ (the apparent singularity is removable) and they coincide in this special case. So we can assume $0 \leq \beta  < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\alpha \geq 0$. The price we have to pay for uniformity is that the coefficients $A_n$ and $B_n$ are complicated functions of their argument and possess removable singularities at the turning point (when $\alpha=\beta=0$). To recover the expansions $(6)$ and $(7)$, one can replace the Airy function and its derivative by their standard [asymptotic expansions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/9.7) but this can be done only if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are bounded away from $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I have recently seen it. I'll careful read it in some hours.

Comment: I understand almost all and now try to do a similar derivation for $I_{i\nu}(\nu z)$. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, careful check with replacements $\nu\rightarrow i\nu$ and $z\rightarrow -iz$ for $K_{\nu}(\nu z)$ expansion has shown that such naive replacement does not work.

Next, Airy functions in $(**)$ should be expanded with **positive argument** (i.e. one should write down expansions for $\text{Ai}(x)$ not for $\text{Ai}(-x)$). In large $\nu$ limit, the second term in $(**)$ does not contribute because it contains greater negative power of $\nu$ in compare with the first term with $\text{Ai}(\beta)$ function ($7/6$ vs $1/2$). For Airy function, the following expansion holds,
$$Ai(x)\sim \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{2\sqrt{\pi}x^{1/4}},\quad \gamma=\frac{2}{3}x^{3/2}.$$
Accurate substitution of all the quantities gives the also called *Debye expansion* (expansion in terms of *elementary* functions, not in special functions), which is $(*)$.

The same procedure can be performed for $I_{i\nu}(z)$. The uniform expansion of such function in terms of Airy functions was derived by Dunster, 1990. However, in this paper there is a typo (it seems): the argument of Airy functions should be $(-\nu^{2/3}\xi)$ (cf. with expansion for $L_{i\nu}(z)$ from this paper).

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Note that Olver's result is eq. $(3)$ in Balogh's paper. You just replace the Airy function and its derivative in Balogh's *uniform* expansion by their [asymptotic series](http://dlmf.nist.gov/9.7.ii) and re-arrange the result to obtain Olver's.

Comment: Your derivation of the result from the expansion of $K_\nu(\nu z)$ works because that expansion is valid for $|\arg \nu|\le \frac{\pi}{2}$ when $z$ is outside the eye-shaped region (Fig. 8.3 on page 380 of Olver's book).

Comment: @Gary , could you please clarify: is it correct that replacements $\nu\rightarrow i\nu$ and $z\rightarrow-iz$ does not work or not? Then, could please comment the case of $K_{-i\nu}(\nu z)$ and $I_{-i\nu}(\nu z)$? I really look for these expansions

Comment: The replacement works at least when $\nu>0$ and $z>1$ in $i\nu$ and $-i z$. Note that $K_{-i\nu}(\nu z) =K_{i\nu}(\nu z)$ and $I_{ - i\nu } (\nu z) = I_{i\nu } (\nu z) - \frac{2}{{\pi i}}\sinh (\pi \nu )K_{i\nu } (\nu z)$.

Comment: I will post a detailed answer tomorrow on the validity of the expansion of $K_\nu(\nu z)$.

Comment: @Gary , hm, naively I assummed that when I change $i\nu \rightarrow -i\nu$, I should write $K_{i\nu}(\nu z)\rightarrow K_{-i\nu z}(-\nu z)$, isn't it?

Comment: See the connection formulas when $\nu\to-\nu$ [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.27). Note that you first use these connection formulae and replace $z$ by $\nu z$ afterwards.